# Python pandas: set row and col to zeros if element is zero?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the following python interview questions using Pandas:

Given a m x n matrix, if an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0. Do it in-place.
without using (enumerate)!!!

Here are some examples:

## Example 1

[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]  # input

[[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]  # output

## Example 2

[[0, 1, 2, 0], [3, 4, 5, 2], [1, 3, 1, 5]]  # input

[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 4, 5, 0], [0, 3, 1, 0]]  # output

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: The solution can be found on [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/set-matrix-zeroes/solution/).

Comment: for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            if (matrix[i][j]==0):
                row=i
                col=j
                matrix[i][j]='a'
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
             for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
                      if (i == row or j == col):
                          matrix[i][j]='a'
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
               if (matrix[i][j]=="a"):
                          matrix[i][j]=0                      
    return (matrix)

Comment: The question asks OP to use pandas. See first line `following python interview questions using Pandas`

Comment: didn't learn the Pandas yet :)

Comment: So how are you expected to solve using pandas if you haven't learnt pandas. I recommend you start learning basics of pandas before you attempt this. If you were to look at non-Pandas solution, then you can use for loop and iterate thru it. Alternatively use numpy to solve for it. Assume you have exposure to numpy

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
lst = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df_result = df.copy(deep=True)
df_result.loc[df.eq(0).any(axis=1)] = 0
df_result.loc[:, df.eq(0).any(axis=0)] = 0

result = df_result.values.tolist()
```

output:

```
[[1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using only built-in Python functions:

```
# Example data (list)
lst = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

# For each row, if any of the values in the row is 0, replace all the values with 0
# Obs: I'm using a `list comprehension` to make the code shorter
for row in lst:
    if any([value==0 for value in row]):
        row[:] = [0] * len(row)
```

Using `numpy`:

```
# Import and create the array from the list
import numpy as np
a = np.array(lst)

# Set zeros in-place
a[(a==0).any(1), :] = 0
```

Using `pandas`:

```
# Import and create the dataframe from the list
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

# Set zeros in-place
df.iloc[df.eq(0).any(1), :] = 0
```

The output for all of them is the same (rows with all zeros if there's at least one original zero on them). That logic was applied in all examples here. As you're still learning nested lists in Python, I would recommend to continue your studies with Python built-in classes, methods, functions, and etc. Afterwards you may want to take a look how indexing works in `numpy` and `pandas` so that you can get a better understanding of the code here.

---

Output:

```
print(lst)
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

print(a)
[[1 1 1]
 [0 0 0]
 [1 1 1]]

# ignore the first line and column,
# as they indicate the row and column names, respectively:
print(df)
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  0  0  0
2  1  1  1
```

Comment: knocked it out of the park :) I got tied up and wanted to share similar output. We can do it for column as well. df.iloc[,df.eq(0).any(0)] = 0 for column. The trick is to ensure we check df but update df1 (a copy of it) otherwise df would already have all columns with 0 on the ith row where it found a 0.

Comment: Thanks for commenting out @JoeFerndz! But the columns are updated only in the ith row (it there's 0 on it) so that it wouldn't change the columns (values) from other rows. I don't think we need a copy at all. About the doing it for columns, yeah, nice! Thx for sharing :)